# PHP-SPO upload large file - The request message is too big

Tags: php, sharepoint

I'm using PHP-SPO (https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) to upload files from my webserver to Sharepoint. It works, except for large files, where I get the message "The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes in Sharepoint"

This is my code so far:

```
$targetLibraryTitle = 'Backups/Chamilo/' . $chamiloCode . '/';
$parentFolder = $this->sharePointAPI->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(dirname($targetLibraryTitle));
$parentFolder->getFolders()->add(basename($targetLibraryTitle));
$this->sharePointAPI->executeQuery();
$targetList = $this->sharePointAPI->getWeb()->getLists()->getByTitle($targetLibraryTitle);

try {
    $fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
    $fileCreationInformation->Content = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $fileCreationInformation->Url = basename($filePath);
    $uploadFile = $this->sharePointAPI->getWeb()
                ->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetLibraryTitle)
                ->getFiles()
                ->add($fileCreationInformation);
    $this->sharePointAPI->executeQuery();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd(__FILE__ . ' - regel: ' . __LINE__, $chamiloCode, $e->getMessage());
}
```

I know it has to do with limits set by Sharepoint. But I cannot find how to solve this.

Any help please!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it. It is not possible to upload files with the Graph larger than 4MB.
So I used this script:

```
$subFolder = 'Chamilo/' . $chamiloCode;
$fileName = basename($filePath);
try {
    $reqBody = [
        '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' => 'rename | fail | replace',
        'description'                       => 'backup ' . $chamiloCode,
        'fileSystemInfo'                    => ['@odata.type' => 'microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo'],
        'name'                              => $fileName,
    ];
    $uploadSession = $this->graphClient->createRequest(
            self::REQUEST_TYPE_POST,
            self::APP_ENDPOINT_DRIVES
            . '/' . self::SHAREPOINT_GROUP_IT_BACKUP_FOLDER_ID . '/root:/'
            . $subFolder . '/' . $fileName
            . ':/createUploadSession'
        )
        ->attachBody($reqBody)
        ->setReturnType(Office365UploadSession::class)
        ->execute();

    $handle = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
    $fileSize = fileSize($filePath);
    $chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    $numberOfFragments = ceil($fileSize / $chunkSize);

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $currentPosition = ftell($handle);
        $contents = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
        $nextPosition = ftell($handle);

        $resp = $this->graphClient->createRequest(self::REQUEST_TYPE_PUT, $uploadSession->getUploadUrl())
                ->addHeaders(
                    [
                        'Connection'     => 'keep-alive',
                        'Content-Length' => (strlen($contents)),
                        'Content-Range'  => 'bytes ' . $currentPosition
                           . '-' . ($nextPosition - 1)
                           . '/' . $fileSize,
                    ]
                )
                ->setReturnType(Office365UploadSession::class)
                ->attachBody($contents)
                ->execute();
            }
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->handleException($e);
 }
```